# How to sum constants if the values of a row contian a specific value in excel?

Tags: excel, sum

I have the following row in excel:

```
12 4 12p 12a 12b
```

I need to sum this elements with their values from the legend.

```
12 = 12;
4 = 4;
12p = 12,5;
12a = 12,2;
12b = 12,3;
```

For example

```
=12 + 4 + 12,5 + 12,2 + 12,3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the elements within one cell as a single string of text, the optimal approach would be to start by using text-to-column to split them up. So you'll have 12 in A, 4 in B, 12p in C, 12a in D, 12b in E. If that's not an option, I can show you string manipulations that can be an alternative.

You'll need to turn your "legend" into a look-up table, (perhaps on sheet2?), with column A having: p, a, b, etc.. and column B having the relative values.

Once that's done, place this formula on sheet1, in F column:

```
=A2+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2),Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE),0)
```

Then drag it to the right 5 times, and it will have the values of the elements "translated".

You can sum the translated range easily.

Comment: I need to have an invisible cells for the translated values right?
Is there a way to do it without helper cells. The legend is in new sheet.

Comment: Yes, of course. Just add them up in the same cell. I.e. =A2+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2),Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE),0) + B2+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(B2),Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE),0) + C2+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(C2),Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE),0) .......